# Unable to turn on the hotspot in my laptop

Tags: windows-10, hotspot

I'm trying to turn on the hotspot in my Dell XPS 15 (L502x), but whenever I click the turn on slider, it slides back to the off position.

I tried most of the fixes I found, but none on them helped.

I tried doing this while connected through both the LAN and WiFi.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to Gino Des's answer in this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/we-cant-set-up-mobile-hotspot/683338d1-3c66-43ed-8ae0-76626e183552

You can try the following steps:
Method 1: Turn off Bluetooth on your device and then try setting up a Mobile hotspot again. You can quickly disable Bluetooth in the Action Center.

Method 2: Run the Network Adapter Troubleshooter. This troubleshooter is an automated tool which finds and fixes the common issues with the Network Adapter Settings on the computer. Kindly follow the steps below:

1. Click **Start**.
2. On the search bar, type **Troubleshooting**, and click on **Troubleshooting** from the results.
3. Click on **Network and Internet**.
4. Under **Network**, click on **Network Adapter**.

Method 3: Update your network and Wi-Fi drivers. To update, follow the steps below:

1. Press **Windows key + X** and click on **Device manager**.
2. **Locate Network adapters** and click on the arrow to expand it.
3. Right click on your network and Wi-Fi adapter, and click on **Update Driver Software**.
4. You can also find updated drivers on your computer manufacturer's website. If you need further assistance, we recommend that you contact your manufacturer.

Hope these can help you.

Comment: I dont have bluetooth feature in my laptop and I also tried updating the drivers but that isn't helping. Thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to select a valid internet connection to share. Select the drop-down menu that says "Network" and switch it to "WiFi" or "Ethernet" and see if that allows you to create a hotspot network.

Comment: That drop down is always disabled irrespective of the type of connection i am connected to.